# Generate path template from controller and action name

Tags: asp.net

I've been using the `LinkGenerator` to generate links to other endpoints in my API by doing this:

```
var link = LinkGenerator
    .GetUriByAction(httpContext, actionName, controllerName, values);
```

This has been working great but now I have a case where I'd like to know the path template to a specific action, without the substituted values. Is there a simple way to do it?